# Making labels in charts selectable/editable in VB

Tags: vb.net, text, mschart, inline-editing

Just like in excel for a graph you can double click on a title, series name, or axis label and then you are able to type in that space. What do I need to do so I can do that for my charts? Clueless on where to start. Seems I may have to create a custom label?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HitTest method of the chart.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Chart1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseDoubleClick
        Dim h As HitTestResult = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y) 'Perform the HitTest with the mouse position that was clicked
        If h.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.AxisTitle OrElse _
            h.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.Axis Then 'Check the type of the element of the chart that was clicked
            Dim s As String = InputBox("Please enter a new title!", "", h.Axis.Title) 'Prompt for a new title
            If s <> "" Then h.Axis.Title = s 'Assign the new title
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 20 'Put some data in the chart to make the axes visible
            Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(i, i ^ 2)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

You basically use the mouse location for the `HitTest` method. The `ChartElementType` defines what element was clicked at the position. If it's the title of the axis or the axis itself it will prompt you with an InputBox for a new title and assigns this title.

The InputBox is pretty old and shouldn't really be used but I was lazy and it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, what I'm referring to lives in [DataVisualization.Charting.TextAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Along with that one, are many more type of annotations.

A TextAnnotation allows: AnchorMoving, Moving, PathEditing, Resizing, Selecting, and TextEditing. All of which I'm looking for.

Simple setup:

```
Dim anno As New DataVisualization.Charting.TextAnnotation
anno.AllowTextEditing = true
anno.AllowSelecting = true
anno.AllowMoving = true
anno.AllowResizing = true
anno.x = 50
anno.y = 50
anno.text = "Your Text"
chart.annotations.add(xAxisAnno)
```

Comment: I still need to figure out how to place the annotation over the spot where the axis title would go.